# How do I conditionally install a file with WiX based on the target machine (32bit or 64bit)?

Tags: windows, wix, 32bit-64bit

I have a file that has a 32bit version and a 64bit version.  If I install my application on a 32bit machine, I want the 32bit version of the file to be installed.  Likewise, the 64bit version should get installed if the installation is run on a 64bit machine.  How do I check which type of machine the installer is being run on with WiX?

Please, no one-line answers.  I'm looking for specific WiX tags and where to put them in my WiX script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could *probably* just do two separate components, using the conditions

```
 VersionNT64
```

and

```
 Not VersionNT64
```

But the correct way is to compile separate installers for 32 and 64 bit OS's and 64-bit components should also be marked as such (with `Win64="yes"`) - I don't know if it's even possible to mark a Windows Installer package as targeted towards both Intel and x64. Only time I've ever done a mixed architecture installation is with NSIS, all my WiX installers have separate installers for each architecture.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way of doing so is to compile two setups, one for 32 (x86) and one for 64 (amd64).  Then you package those two msi inside a single msi and run the appropriate one at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base wxs file using environment or preprocessor variables and fill in the required attributes before compiling. Another option would be running a script before the build that includes different GUIDs in the file for specific installation.
In short, I don't think there is a simple way of building installers for different architectures, so you have to use additional utilities.