# Install VC++ Runtime 64-bit if system is 64-bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project, msvcrt

I am creating a Visual Studio 2010 Setup project for installing my application. My application works by having multiple executable for different system bitness, and detects if you are running on a 32-bit or 64-bit system.

I'd like to have the Visual C++ 2010 x64 Runtime installed by the installer if it is a 64-bit system. Setting this as a prerequisite, disables installation on 32-bit systems. Is there any way to set this as a prerequisite, but only on 64-bit systems, without resorting to two different installers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create separate MSI files for the 64-bit version and the 32-bit version to deal with the specialities of WOW64.

It is not possible to have one single MSI install both a 64-bit and a 32-bit version:

> **[Different Packages are Required for Different Processor Architectures](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures/)**

Because you will have separate MSI files it should be easy to add the 64-bit VC++ Runtime Redistributables to the 64-bit MSI and the 32-bit ones to the 32-bit MSI respectively.

Of course, you may create a bootstrapper that checks the system architecture and then launches the respective MSI file. I believe [dotNetInstaller](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotnetinstaller) offers such a mechanism as has been indicated in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724956/single-msi-to-install-correct-32-or-64-bit-c-sharp-application).

Comment: How do I do this in VS2010? Can I create two setup projects, and have the 32-bit installer include the 64-bit installer? If so, how do I make it so that it installs the 64-bit version depending on the bitness of the system?

Comment: I think my solution to this is going to be to drop the x64-requirement during installation. When you start the program, I will prompt the user to download and install the correct package (direct link) to make the program work properly. At some later stage I might add a more streamlined approach that automatically downloads and installs it (with the permission of the user, of course).