# launching correct installer for 32 and 64-bit apps

Tags: installation, 32bit-64bit

We have an application which, for various reasons, needs to be compiled as both a 32-bit and 64-bit app.  The thing is, we want to distribute both setup files (msi) on a single CD.  Is there a launch condition or autorun.inf entry that we can use to know which setup.exe to launch?  Or do we need to write a separate little exe that gets called by autorun, and which determines the OS, and calls the appropriate setup.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be any 32/64bit detection support inherent in [autorun.inf files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144200%28VS.85%29.aspx).

The convention that most applications which supply a 32 and 64 bit MSI follow is similar to the second option you mention.

1. Create a single 32bit setup.exe application (so that it will run on either platform). Ideally this will be written in C/C++ so that it is as small and quick as possible, and has no dependencies on other libraries/frameworks (eg. static linked).
2. Detect if you are running on 64bit or not (see sample code for Windows API [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function
3. Execute the appropriate MSI

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom action to detect the OS, then call the right installer.

I've given an example here: [Single MSI to install correct 32 or 64 bit c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724956/single-msi-to-install-correct-32-or-64-bit-c-application/4518939#4518939)