# Which package of .NET 3.5 should I use for distribution?

Tags: .net

I want to include .net framework 3.5 in my prequisets , I don't know which package shall I include

any suggestion please

I mean the full 233 mb framework , the distribution one , or what any download link will be highly appretiated I asume the use doesn't have any internet connection and I don't know its operating system if x86 or not

Answer (score 2):

CLR itself is a native code application so it can only be 32 or 64 bit at a time. You'll need to bundle both 32bit and 64bit frameworks with your application. You'll also need to configure the .NET installer bootstrapper to not to retrieve the correct .NET package from the internet, rather to use the bundled ones.

Comment: If you're not using the `System.Web` namespace in your application, you can use the client profile packages. If you want to make sure that no problems arise in the future if you update the application to use `System.Web` namespace, install the full package, it is only +10mb larger.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your clients don't have internet connection, you should add it as a pre-requisite and add the installer in the setup project.

You should make a single installer for each version.

You can then make a single installer that chooses the right version to install.
[Single MSI to install correct 32 or 64 bit c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724956/single-msi-to-install-correct-32-or-64-bit-c-application/4518939#4518939)

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of the frameworks. One targets 32 bit and is normally referred to as i386 and the other is the 64 bit installer.

Search on the Microsoft site for .Net framework 3.5 redist, it will bring you to the redistributable page that you can download a version that can be packaged with your deployment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: .NET Compact Framework 3.5 Redistributable  is this enough to open application developed on visual studio 2008 and does it target x86 and 64 bit windows

Comment: AMH: No, the Compact Framework is for installing the .NET framework on phones and stuff, not on the desktop.

Comment: So which distribution package shall I install could you give me download link because I get confused

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d0e5dea7-ac26-4ad7-b68c-fe5076bba986